# dplyr: Filter within years prior to marked time period

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, dummy-variable

I want have a list of year-country specific dummies and I want to also mark years *two years* prior to those years that are marked.

The data looks like this

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~year, ~country, ~occurrence, 
  #--|--|----
  2003, "USA", 1,
  2004, "USA", 0,
  2005, "USA", 0,
  2006, "USA", 0,
  2007, "USA", 0,
  2008, "USA", 0,
  2009, "USA", 0,
  2010, "USA", 0,
  2011, "USA", 1,
  2012, "USA", 0,
  2013, "USA", 0,
  2005, "FRA", 0,
  2006, "FRA", 0,
  2007, "FRA", 1,
  2008, "FRA", 1,
  2009, "FRA", 0,
  2010, "FRA", 0,
  2011, "FRA", 0,
  2012, "FRA", 0,
  2013, "FRA", 0,
  2014, "FRA", 0,
  2015, "FRA", 1
)
```

So for `"USA"` I also want to put a `1` into column `occurence` for the years 2009 and 2010 and for `FRA` the years 2005, 2006, 2013 and 2014.

I thought about doing something like this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(occurence = ifelse("not sure what to put here"),
                            1,
                            0))
```

But I'm not sure how to tell R only to filter for the years I want.

Comment: you need the following condition: `(country == "USA" & year %in% 2009:2010) | (country == "FRA" & year %in% c(2005,2006,2013,2014))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another dplyr solution:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  mutate(
        occurrence=ifelse( lead(occurrence, 1) %in% 1 | 
                           lead(occurrence, 2) %in% 1, 
                           1, occurrence)
         )

# A tibble: 22 x 3
# Groups:   country [2]
    year country occurrence
   <dbl>   <chr>      <dbl>
 1  2003     USA          1
 2  2004     USA          0
 3  2005     USA          0
 4  2006     USA          0
 5  2007     USA          0
 6  2008     USA          0
 7  2009     USA          1
 8  2010     USA          1
 9  2011     USA          1
10  2012     USA          0
11  2013     USA          0
12  2005     FRA          1
13  2006     FRA          1
14  2007     FRA          1
15  2008     FRA          1
16  2009     FRA          0
17  2010     FRA          0
18  2011     FRA          0
19  2012     FRA          0
20  2013     FRA          1
21  2014     FRA          1
22  2015     FRA          1
```

`lead(occurrence, 1) %in% 1` is used instead of `lead(occurrence, 1) == 1` because the latter cannot handle `NA`.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

After grouping by 'country', we can take up to 2 `lead` of 'occurrence' and get the `max` of each row with `pmax` to get the expected output in 'occurrence'

```
df %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(occurrence = pmax(occurrence, lead(occurrence, default = 0),
                     lead(occurrence, default=0, n=2)))
```

---

Or this can be achieved with `data.table` with similar methodology

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,  occurrence := do.call(pmax, shift(occurrence, n = 0:2,
     type = "lead", fill = 0)), country]
df
#    year country occurrence
# 1: 2003     USA          1
# 2: 2004     USA          0
# 3: 2005     USA          0
# 4: 2006     USA          0
# 5: 2007     USA          0
# 6: 2008     USA          0
# 7: 2009     USA          1
# 8: 2010     USA          1
# 9: 2011     USA          1
#10: 2012     USA          0
#11: 2013     USA          0
#12: 2005     FRA          1
#13: 2006     FRA          1
#14: 2007     FRA          1
#15: 2008     FRA          1
#16: 2009     FRA          0
#17: 2010     FRA          0
#18: 2011     FRA          0
#19: 2012     FRA          0
#20: 2013     FRA          1
#21: 2014     FRA          1
#22: 2015     FRA          1
```

Comment: The `data.table` version works for me. The `dplyr` version works on the example data set, but not on my real life dataset. It misses some of my dummies and gets attaches some lagged dummies instead of the leads I want. I'm not sure why.